# Distance between two latitude longitude Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Coor"
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lat numeric,
     lng numeric,
    CONSTRAINT pk__coor PRIMARY KEY ( id)
)
```

TABLESPACE pg_default;

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."Coor"
    OWNER to postgres;






CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_distance(lat1 float, lon1 float, lat2 float, lon2 float, units varchar)
RETURNS float AS $dist$
    DECLARE
        dist float = 0;
        radlat1 float;
        radlat2 float;
        theta float;
        radtheta float;
    BEGIN
        IF lat1 = lat2 AND lon1 = lon2
            THEN RETURN dist;
        ELSE
            radlat1 = pi() * lat1 / 180;
            radlat2 = pi() * lat2 / 180;
            theta = lon1 - lon2;
            radtheta = pi() * theta / 180;
            dist = sin(radlat1) * sin(radlat2) + cos(radlat1) * cos(radlat2) * cos(radtheta);

            IF dist > 1 THEN dist = 1; END IF;

            dist = acos(dist);
            dist = dist * 180 / pi();
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

            IF units = 'K' THEN dist = dist * 1.609344; END IF;
            IF units = 'N' THEN dist = dist * 0.8684; END IF;

            RETURN dist;
        END IF;
    END;
$dist$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is sample select to execute  calculate_distance.

```
SELECT calculate_distance(13.08, 80.27, 12.29, 76.63, 'M');
SELECT calculate_distance(13.08, 80.27, 12.29, 76.63, 'K');
```

The final output should be in the below format

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."distance"
(
     
   fromname character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    toname character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
     distancemiles character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
     diskm character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" `
)
```

I want to find distance between three cities Chennai to Kochi , Chennai to Mysore , and Kochi to Mysore

```
1   "Chennai"   13.08   80.27
2   "Kochi"     9.93    76.26
3   "Mysore"    12.29   76.63
```

OUTPUT

```
Chennai Mysore 250 miles 404 km
Chennai Kochi
Kochi Mysore
```

Comment: When working with geo data, consider using [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) instead. This handles such calculations of distances between lat-long coordinates natively.

Answer (score 1):

I needed torewrite your function and taböe a bit, as you´r design caused lots of problems

as you want a a row you need to specify the type of row you want toreciece, so distance seem like the best chance

It now returns a row of the style distance

You need to expand the hole things, as you need also to pass the name and last name.

Your function is built that it only returns only Km or miles, like you can see in the output.

This gives you a start, on that you can adept your function

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."distance"
(
     
   fromname TEXT COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    toname TEXT COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
     distancemiles float,
     diskm  float 
)
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_distance(lat1 float, lon1 float, lat2 float, lon2 float, units varchar)
RETURNS SETOF "distance" AS $$
    DECLARE
        dist float = 0;
  distkm float = 0;
  distMiles float = 0;
        radlat1 float;
        radlat2 float;
        theta float;
        radtheta float;
    BEGIN
        IF lat1 = lat2 AND lon1 = lon2
            THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT 'userA','userlastA',distMiles,distkm ;
        ELSE
            radlat1 = pi() * lat1 / 180;
            radlat2 = pi() * lat2 / 180;
            theta = lon1 - lon2;
            radtheta = pi() * theta / 180;
            dist = sin(radlat1) * sin(radlat2) + cos(radlat1) * cos(radlat2) * cos(radtheta);

            IF dist > 1 THEN dist = 1; END IF;

            dist = acos(dist);
            dist = dist * 180 / pi();
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

            IF units = 'K' THEN distkm = dist * 1.609344; END IF;
            IF units = 'M' THEN distMiles = dist * 0.8684; END IF;

            RETURN QUERY SELECT 'userA','userlastA' ,distMiles,distkm  ;
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
SELECT * FROM  calculate_distance(13.08, 80.27, 12.29, 76.63, 'M');
SELECT * FROM calculate_distance(13.08, 80.27, 12.29, 76.63, 'K');
```

| fromname | toname | distancemiles | diskm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| userA | userlastA | 218.26626129516504 | 0 |

| fromname | toname | distancemiles | diskm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| userA | userlastA | 0 | 404.49734916836263 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ct5yHtUk)

But an approach with loops which would be neede is verslow, so that maybe another approach is necessary

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Coor"
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    name Text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lat numeric,
     lng numeric,
    CONSTRAINT pk__coor PRIMARY KEY ( id)
);
   
INSERT INTO "Coor"
    ( "name", "lat", "lng")
VALUES
    ( '"Chennai"', 13.08, 80.27),
    ( '"Kochi"', 9.93, 76.26),
    ( '"Mysore"', 12.29, 76.63)
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 3
> ```

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."distance"
(
     
   fromname TEXT COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    toname TEXT COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
     distancemiles float,
     diskm  float 
)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_distance
  (fromname  Text ,lat1 float, lon1 float, toname text,lat2 float, lon2 float, units varchar)
RETURNS SETOF "distance" AS $$
    DECLARE
        dist float = 0;
  distkm float = 0;
  distMiles float = 0;
        radlat1 float;
        radlat2 float;
        theta float;
        radtheta float;
    BEGIN
        IF lat1 = lat2 AND lon1 = lon2
            THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT fromname,toname,distMiles,distkm ;
        ELSE
            radlat1 = pi() * lat1 / 180;
            radlat2 = pi() * lat2 / 180;
            theta = lon1 - lon2;
            radtheta = pi() * theta / 180;
            dist = sin(radlat1) * sin(radlat2) + cos(radlat1) * cos(radlat2) * cos(radtheta);

            IF dist > 1 THEN dist = 1; END IF;

            dist = acos(dist);
            dist = dist * 180 / pi();
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

            distkm = dist * 1.609344; 
            distMiles = dist * 0.8684;

            RETURN QUERY SELECT fromname,toname ,distMiles,distkm  ;
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION
> ```

```
create or replace function fn_list() 
  returns table(fromname Text,toname Text,distMiles Float,distkm Float) 
as $$
begin
  -- do some work....
  return query
WITH CTE As ( 
  SELECT c1.name as Fromname, c1.lat lat1, c1.lng lon1,
  c2.name toname, c2. lat lat2, c2.lng lon2
  FROM "Coor" c1 JOIN "Coor" c2 ON c1.id < c2.id)
SELECT CTE.Fromname, CTE.toname, 
  acos(sin(pi() * lat1 / 180) * sin(pi() * lat2 / 180) 
  + cos(pi() * lat1 / 180) * cos(pi() * lat2 / 180) * cos(pi() * (lon1 - lon2) / 180)) * 180 / pi() * 60 * 1.1515 * 0.8684 as distancemiles
  ,  acos(sin(pi() * lat1 / 180) * sin(pi() * lat2 / 180) 
  + cos(pi() * lat1 / 180) * cos(pi() * lat2 / 180) * cos(pi() * (lon1 - lon2) / 180)) * 180 / pi() * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 as distanceKm 
FROM CTE;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM fn_list()
```

| fromname | toname | distmiles | distkm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Chennai" | "Kochi" | 302.13074782483 | 559.9174415331682 |
| "Chennai" | "Mysore" | 218.26626129516504 | 404.49734916836263 |
| "Kochi" | "Mysore" | 143.26021902027512 | 265.49398194261363 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nU1qhORF)

Comment: I need a query for n rows here are three rows ,If I have three locations a,b,c I need a to b , a to c and b to c.                                                         
1   "Chennai"   13.08   80.27
2   "Kochi"     9.93    76.26
3   "Mysore"    12.29   76.63
OUTPUT

                          
Chennai Mysore 250 miles 404 km
Chennai Kochi
Kochi Mysore

Comment: you can easily adept it, this shows you how to get startet

Comment: and you need something liek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841910/input-table-for-pl-pgsql-function to get back a table

Comment: I created this but  I am getting errorSELECT   a.id 
      ,a.Name
      ,a.lat
      ,a.lng
  , b.id 
      ,b.Name
      ,b.lat
      ,b.lng
   , calculate_distance(a.lat, a.lng, b.lat, b.lng, 'M') 'MILES'
   , calculate_distance(a.lat, a.lng, b.lat, b.lng, 'k') 'KMS'
   FROM   public."Coor"  a  cross join    public."Coor"   b
  where  a.id <> b.id

Comment: I got this 
SELECT   a.id 
      ,a.Name
      ,a.lat
      ,a.lng
  , b.id 
      ,b.Name
      ,b.lat
      ,b.lng
   , calculate_distance(a.lat, a.lng, b.lat, b.lng, 'M')  miles
   , calculate_distance(a.lat, a.lng, b.lat, b.lng, 'K')  kms
   FROM   public."Coor"  a  cross join    public."Coor"   b
  where  a.id <> b.id

Comment: you would make this like https://dbfiddle.uk/y9boxf2x now you can call the function like described in the last link and add your distance code to it